# Transform a DataTable with a single column to a Dictionary where the index is the key

Tags: c#, linq

Simple question. I have a `Dictionary<int, double>` that I wish to populate from the columns `DataTable`. So for a `DataTable` with a single column:

```
23.9
39009.0
32.99
12.1
```

I want a `Dictionary<int, double>` with

```
{ 1, 23.9 },
{ 2, 39009.0 },
{ 3, 32.99 },
{ 4, 12.1 }
```

where the key is auto-incrementing. To do this I have written some basic code:

```
Dictionary<int, double> d = new Dictionary<int, double>();
List<double> tmp = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => Double.Parse(c[i].ToString())).ToList();

int index = 1;
foreach (var j in tmp)
    d.Add(index++, j);
```

Can I do this with LINQ with a single query? I am not a LINQ fan-boy, who likes to write it for the sake of it, but I do like to better my LINQ skills and I could not seem to work out a way to do this using a single LINQ query although it is probably possible.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I do this with LINQ with a single query?

Yes

```
Dictionary<int, double> dict = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
    .ToDictionary(x=> x.index + 1, x=> x.row.Field<double>(0));
```

Comment: That's sweet. I am unfamiliar with what `new { row, index }` is doing here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thats a so called [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) similar to a class without a name. It has two properties (in this case): `row` and `index` with the correct types(`DataRow`+`int`). I need both in `ToDictionary`. But since only [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) (and `Where`) has an overload that gives me the index of the element in the sequence i need to persist it somehow.

Comment: @Killercam - Tim is using the select which gives the element value and an index to create a new type that has both of these values in the projected sequence.

Comment: I suppose where this is confusing is how the compiler is clever enough to derive the anonymous types from the `new { ... }` statement. The parser in this case must estblish this from the `.ToDictionary(...)` statement...

Comment: @Killercam: no, the compiler gets it from `new { row, index }`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - doesn't the type information for your new statement come from the Select prototype (first argument is a function with two parameters double and int)?

Answer (score 1):

Some might find this simpler...

```
int index = 1;
Dictionary<int, double> dict = dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(x=>index++, x => x);
```

Replace `x => x` with however you go from your elements to the double value required.

(eg `x => x.row.Field<double>(0)` if it is a datatable with one column)

Comment: But there is no extension method `ToDictionary` for a `DataTable`. This is not even possible if you use `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: I edited it to use `AsEnumerable()` since my testing was on a list and not a table.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
d = tmp.Select( ( x, i ) => new { Value = x, Index = i } ).ToDictionary( pair => pair.Index, pair => pair.Value );
```